# how to create a date from a given string with a specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, format

My problem is the following:
I have a var in javascript that represents a date in the following format in the following format 'dd/mm/yyyy'
so, if I have 01/03/2024, this would be  1st of March, 2024

I am trying to manipulate this, my problem:
`var test = "01/03/2024";`
if I create a`var myDate = new Date(test);`
and I see what's inside myDate it will point to the 3rd of January, 2024.
Is there any way to format the date when creating  a new Date object?

I explored with moment.js but it's erroring somewhere
I tried the following var myDate=moment(test, 'dd/mm/yyyy').toDate();
but it errors when trying to manipulate myDate at a later stage.

Comment: Built–in parsing of unsupported date formats (i.e. not one of those mentioned [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/?_gl=1*1imrdco*_ga*MTA4MDQyMjY5MS4xNzAyNDU1MTI1*_ga_TDCK4DWEPP*MTcwMjQ1NTEyNS4xLjEuMTcwMjQ1NTEzOC4wLjAuMA..&_ga=2.75594645.1851633646.1702455126-1080422691.1702455125#sec-date.parse)) is implementation dependent. Most will assume m/d/y so  01/03/2024 represents 3 Jan 2024. Other formats may give differing results in different implementations, including `Invalid Date`. For reliability, manually parse strings (a library can help), don't rely on the built–in parser.

Answer (score 0):

Split and reverse the string with '-' and attach 'T00:00:00' and pass to the Date's constructor:

```js
const date = new Date('01/03/2024'.split('/').reverse().join('-') + 'T00:00:00');

console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```